# How to get string that will be sent to the MongoDB server in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

The title is the question.

What i want to achieve is to get the string that will be sent to the MongoDB server for debugging purposes.

Right now, i only know how to do it with aggregate() and find() method like this:

```
var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Gt(x => x.Age, 25);
var text = collection.Find(filter).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

This will print out **find({ "Age" : { "$gt" : 25 } })** which is the text that will be sent to the MongoDB server.

But i don't know how to get the text if i for example use update or delete.

Is it possible to get the text from those other functions?